# Collapsing toolbar when checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, pug

This is probably basic stuff, but i'm new to bootstrap & jQuery

I have a table with a checkbox at each line.

I'm trying to display a collapsed element when **atleast one** checkbox is checked

As of now, it collapses on each checkbox click

```
#Foo.collapse
  | This div (Foo) is hidden by default

td
  label(data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#Foo')
    input(type="checkbox", value=i, name="checkbox")
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but here's what worked for me.

```
$(".check").click(function(){
  var n = $("input:checked").length;
  if (n > 0) {
    $(".collapse").collapse('show');
  } else {
    $(".collapse").collapse('hide');              
  }
});
```

---

```
input.check(type="checkbox", value=i, name="checkbox")
```